# JQuery upload, preview, crop

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, jcrop

I have an upload script which shows a preview of the photo that has been uploaded using JQuery. Now I want to apply JCrop to that preview image but it is not loading the photo into the JCrop area. The script seems to work and the JCrop area open up where the preview is but no photo is shown. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

```
function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#avatar').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#imgInp").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
            $('#avatar').Jcrop(); // JCROP Displayed but no Image shown
        });

<img id="avatar" src="#" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' id="imgInp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Internet Explorer? Internet Explorer < 10 does not support the File API, which you use when trying to get input.files. So the reader is never set and loader (although I do believe the reader is also unsupported in IE).
Unfortunately I am looking into a similar issue, so can only tell you why it doesn't work, not how to make it work (yet), but most mentioned options are using flash or upload the image to a temp file.

IE support for File API: http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api

File API: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: No, I'm using Firefox. I sorted the problem (although I can't remember how I did it now) - Good to know about the support for IE though, thanks

Comment: Please post when you do remember, might be useful to someone :)